# Fulltext index not matching column list on mysql

Tags: mysql

I use contao 4.9 and have problems with a view that only arise when using mysql 5.7.35 instead of mariadb. The query that creates the view is the following:

```
CREATE
OR REPLACE VIEW `tl_news4ward_articleWithTags` AS
SELECT
tl_news4ward_article.*,
GROUP_CONCAT(tag) AS tags
FROM
tl_news4ward_article
LEFT OUTER JOIN tl_news4ward_tag ON (
    tl_news4ward_tag.pid = tl_news4ward_article.id
)
GROUP BY
tl_news4ward_article.id
```

The interesting part of the tl_news4ward_article table was created as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_news4ward_article` (
`title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`keywords` text,
`description` text,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `pid` (`pid`),
 KEY `alias` (`alias`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=53 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

And tl_news4ward_tag:

```
CREATE TABLE `tl_news4ward_tag` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`pid` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tstamp` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`tag` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `pid` (`pid`),
FULLTEXT KEY `tag` (`tag`)
```

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=103 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

When I run the query `SELECT MATCH (keywords,title,description) AGAINST (' something1 something2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM tl_news4ward_article` it just works, but if I run `SELECT MATCH (keywords,title,description) AGAINST (' something1 something2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score FROM tl_news4ward_articleWithTags` I get an error:

> #1191 - Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list

I can provide more information if needed. **It just works on Mariadb.**

DB Fiddle:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3LN1cAM6aoohaB4a1q6oWb/1

EDIT2:

The code comes from this Contao module: https://github.com/psi-4ward/news4ward/issues/106 we think is supposed to work with MySQL

EDIT3:

More clear compare-fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&rdbms2=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=2f1ab88e65a8acb3bb992a1cf6fb4101

EDIT4:

The above query is simplified - as you can see in the Contao module, the tags column should be included in the score and match as well.

Comment: Have you tried creating a fulltext index on those three columns in the first place?

Comment: Yes, I tried that. But it also doesn’t seem to be necessary because the query on the original table works fine.

Comment: A fulltext search may work without an index, but it is not going to be very effective.

Comment: Also, it seems that mysql requires fulltext index on the underlying table if the table is referenced in a view.

Comment: Do you have the keys enabled on the table? `ALTER TABLE xxx ENABLE KEYS;`

Comment: Yes, I executed your suggested query and it is still not working.

Comment: Is the ALTER call for the table or the view or for both?

Comment: I tried for the 2 tables and for the view. For the view I got an error that said that the view is not is not of type 'BASE TABLE'.

Comment: Please post the CREATE TABLE statement of tl_news4ward_tag as well - I tried without that table on https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3LN1cAM6aoohaB4a1q6oWb/0 and it's not reproducible.

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3LN1cAM6aoohaB4a1q6oWb/1

Comment: @Shadow - Whether you must have a 3-column FT index differs between InnoDB and MyISAM.  Also, I think that InnoDB won't work without the index.

Answer (score 3):

- The error comes from not having an index on the combination of the 3 columns:

  ```
    FULLTEXT(keywords,title,description)
  ```
- You should move to InnoDB, which now has FULLTEXT.  The two tables may need to use the same Engine.  Caution:  There are several details about InnoDB's FULLTEXT that are different than MyISAM's.  Here is a list:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb#fulltext
- MySQL's `VIEWs` are mostly syntactic sugar.  While I have not encountered your specific problem, it seems clear that `VIEW` is getting in the way.
- Did you try explicitly specifying the two 'algorithms' for expanding Views?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html
- If you are having performance problems with the query (once it works), it may be because of doing the `JOIN` *before* doing the filtering.  If you encounter such, we can discuss that in a separate Question.

(From fiddle)

I prefer this way of getting the record, plus tags:

```
SELECT  a.*,
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(tag)
              FROM tl_news4ward_tag AS t
              WHERE t.pid = a.id
        ) AS tags
    FROM  tl_news4ward_article AS a
```

But there is no way (with the current schema) to include `tags` in the `MATCH`.

**4-col FT**

If you decide that you must have `tags` in the `FULLTEXT` index, then the commalist of tags in the main table and get rid of the `tags` table.  Then you need some stored procedures/functions to handle add-tag, del-tag, etc.  Tip:  `FIND_IN_SET('foo', tags)` will come in handy for testing for a particular tag.

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=836cea76364df5678f2e0eec1ba33542 also does not work (adding a FULLTEXT index, switching to InnoDb)

Comment: Also tried all the 3 VIEW algorithms, does not work either (i.e. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=38e0710e2fa1de09bfef4b42b81c12cf)

Comment: @Alex - I think you need to abandon the `VIEW`.  You could also write a bug report at bugs.mysql.com

Comment: It is totally possible that MySQL just does not support this. The strange thing the VIEW code comes from a 3rd Party Plugin which we believe also should work with MySQL.

Comment: The contao news4ward plugin, linked in the question

Comment: In that link, the table needs `FULLTEXT(keywords,tags,title,description)`, since it "MATCHes" on those 4 columns.

Comment: That would be no table, but a view

Comment: The question was a bit wrong, we DO need tags in the MATCH --- how would we need to change the schema to include in into the match? build a additional materialized table or something like this?

Comment: To include `tags` in the `FULLTEXT`, it would have to be a column in the same table, not a computed value from `GROUP_CONCAT`.  Alternatively, you could use FT for the existing 3 columns, then a separate query to check the `tag` table.

Comment: The fun part would be to mix the scores together to get the original behaviour ... but maybe we have to give up the existing behaviour and come up with something similar. The other thing we are thinking of is to update the table on the fly via stored procedures, but that might be overkill?

Comment: @Alex - I recommend a major change to the schema; see my latest addition to my Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use full text indexes on view.

> MySQL doesn't allow any form of indexes on a view, just on it's underlying tables. The reason for this is because MySQL only materializes a view when you select from it, due to the possibility of the underlying tables changing data all the time. If you had a view that returned 10 million rows, you'd have to apply a full text index to it every time you selected from it, and that takes a lot of time.

So the only chance you get is

add

> ```
> ALTER TABLE tl_news4ward_article  
> ADD FULLTEXT(keywords,title,description)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM   tl_news4ward_articleWithTags t1  INNER JOIN ( SELECT MATCH (keywords,title,description) AGAINST (' something1 something2' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS score ,id FROM tl_news4ward_article ) t2
> ON t1.id =  t2.id;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | title     | keywords  | description | tags | score | id
> -: | :-------- | :-------- | :---------- | :--- | ----: | -:
>  1 | something | something | something   | null |     0 |  1
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1af0bfda86c3c07a8ff9082cecb9b871)*

Comment: In 5.6 it looks like this was possible. But thank you for your answer, that helps

Answer (score 1):

Views do not have indexes, so index hints do not apply. Use of index hints when selecting from a view is not permitted.

Comment: The essence of the question is that it seems to work with MariaDB - do you have reference what's the difference here? Or how this can be made work with the given MySQL version, if MariaDB is not available.

Comment: Compare https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=6b51386e18bde16fe7aab9dc7b0c7b88 vs https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=6b51386e18bde16fe7aab9dc7b0c7b88
(the later one works)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2f57263f878de51f6aedeca5dbb0a6e9

Answer (score 1):

This actually might be a MySQL 5.7 regression.

The linked Contao Module's code is 8 years (2014) old:

https://github.com/psi-4ward/news4ward_related/blame/master/RelatedHelper.php#L18

MySQL 5.7 was releasted 6 years (2015) ago.

The code broke was working in 5.6 but does no longer in 5.7

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&rdbms2=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1d875703c4781dad878e64943057de5a

Not sure if this s a bug in MySQL 5.7 or an intended removal of that functionality.

Lowset friction solution might really be to update the Contao module and remove the usage of the VIEW in the queries.